# Making kernel to allow 2processes to access camera at sametime

Tags: custom-roms, camera

Like split cam or obs in windows,
Can i add virtual camera driver or moduel in kernel so that 2 processes in android can use camera at sametime? (One is default and the other is getting video frame)

Comment: Most likely that depends on the camera driver. If it was developed in a way that it can not be used concurrently then you may have to write a complete new driver.

Comment: Assuming Samsung galaxy phone. I thought using virtual driver as mirroring video stream would be possible without writing new driver